# How can I secure a NAS on my home network?

Tags: access-control

So I have a NAS enclosure on my home network (D-Link Share Centre) and I am worried about its security.

It is hard wired into my Sky router (SR102) which I hear the firewall doesn't work on. There is no external or internet access to the device and I keep it patched as and when a patch becomes available.

Access to the device is a via a windows 10 PC with a mapped drive, my concern is that if god forbid I get infected with ransomware then all my files which I store on this device will be affected too.

Is there a way of having the device available to my PC but that would not enable potential ransomware to gain access via my compromised PC?

Comment: You should have Backups done right and/or a versioned access to your files.

Comment: Make sure that the shares need a user and a password. This is the only way to make sure ransomware does not simply encrypt your shares as well.

Comment: @Draugr would be of no help if the OS remembered the password (for example if you mapped the share to a local drive letter).

Comment: That's correct, of course, but then - looking from the malware's perspective - you couldn't speak of a password protected share anymore, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You are absolutely right to be concerned. Ransomware is increasingly prevalent and totally devastating if you are not prepared. Once you make the storage accessible to any client, it is going to be vulnerable and there is little you can do to change that I'm afraid.

Generally, as Marcel commented, there are two things you need to do:

1. If you can (I couldn't see the feature on the D-Link site), have versioning turned on.
2. Have *remote* backups with versioning

#### Versioning

File versions would allow you to roll back any changes and recover deleted files and would be a quick way to be able to recover if ransomware encrypted files for example.

#### Backups

Backups **must** be to an offsite location. They must be automatic, encrypted (preferably locally before sending) and should be versioned since it is is likely that you will have backed up several times before you discover an issue.

Local backups are useful for quick recovery but are worthless for long term information security since a local disaster, burglary, etc will wipe out the backups along with the originals.

Use a cloud backup service or at least have another unit at someone else's house.

If your information is in any way important to you, good backups are utterly essential.

If you are not able to follow this advice, at least make occasional copies of key files such as family photos, financial information, etc. Even the old standby of a DVD or similar that you then take offsite to a friend or family house is better than doing nothing. But with manual backups, you **will** eventually loose data since you will forget to backup something important.

Of course, you should take precautions on your PC too, AV, latest updates and adblocking all help reduce the risk. You might also want to save up and upgrade your router to one with a decent firewall capability.

---

UPDATE: So backups are the most critical thing you need to do regardless of where you are keeping files. Once you've dealt with that, you will find that the better NAS's such as the Synology ones are "simply" low-power Linux computers. As such, they should (Synology certainly do) give you access to the Linux firewall. So you can further protect the NAS by limiting the access to it. How you do that would be the subject of another question though if you check my recent answers to other questions you may get a clue or two ;-)

To protect your PC, again versioned backups are the key. You can back up to the NAS or direct to cloud. If you discover malware, disconnect from the network immediately to limit the damage.

Comment: Thank you all who have replied and apologies to moderators for not getting this question to fit the rules but I am at a loss of how to word the question to fit, i obviously do not meet the elite criteria for technical questioning ability required on this site.

Comment: The only way to change the router is to turn the existing router into modem only mode and add a new router/firewall in front of it which has its obvious appeal but does add yet another electricity eating device onto my already long list of devices, not to mention the amount of cabling. (Sky do not allow their signal to be decoded by anything other than their supplied device).

Comment: Personally, I don't agree with the decision to put it on hold - but then I'm not a moderator. I will update my answer to talk about some additional specific things you can do.

Comment: Julian - this was closed by the community, not moderators.

Comment: @RoryAlsop: Oops, sorry for casting aspersions!